# Multiple roots of one polynomial of degree 4

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I have the following specific polynomial of degree 4:
\begin{align}
 P(x) &= (x_1^2 + x_2^2)^2 + a(x_1 + i x_2)^2(x_1^2 + x_2^2) + \overline{a}
 (x_1-ix_2)^2(x_1^2 + x_2^2)\\
&+b(x_1+ix_2)^4 + \overline{b}(x_1-ix_2)^4, \, x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2.
\end{align}
In addition, I know that coefficients $a,b$ are such that 
\begin{equation}
 P(x) \geq c(x_1^2+x^2_2)^2 , \, c > 0.
\end{equation}

I have a conjecture that $P$ must have only simple (complex) roots. For example, if one will look for the similar polynomial of degree 2, i.e.:
\begin{align}
&Q(x) = (x_1^2 + x_2^2) + a(x_1 + i x_2)^2 + \overline{a}
 (x_1-ix_2)^2,\\
&Q(x) \geq c(x_1^2 + x_2^2)
\end{align}
then one can directly show that the corresponding roots will be only simple. And condition of positivity is used to have that the determinant is not zero.

Comment: In the particular case when $a=0$ the polynomial $Q(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ satisfies the assumption and has a double zero at the origin. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "simple roots" in the case of a polynomial of two variables. And this isn't a polynomial in one complex variable, $x=x_1+x_2i.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to all. Question is not at all well posed. By simple characterstics I meant that in the decomposition of the polynomial it won't appear any monomial of the form:
\begin{equation}
 (x_1 + z x_2)^k,\, z \in \mathbb{C}, \, k\geq 2. 
\end{equation}
The case when $a = 0, b = 0$ is the obvious counterexample, so the conjecture is absolutely not true.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$$P(x_1, x_2) = \Re F(x) = |x|^4\Re G(y),$$
where
$$F(x) = |x|^4 + 2a|x|^2x^2 + 2bx^4,\quad G(y) = 1 + ay + by^2,\quad y=\left(\dfrac x{|x|}\right)^2.$$
This means that every root $|y| \ge 1$ defines the infinity family of solutions
$$x = r\sqrt y,\quad r \in\mathbb R.$$